# Which version of Mac OS (Hackintosh) , i can install on my Intel PC

Tags: macos

My PC configuration is

Processor: Genuine Intel(R) CPU 2140 @ 1.60GHz, 1600 Mhz,2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

BIOS Version/Date: LENOVO 2VKT79AUS, 7/4/2007

RAM : 1.50 GB

HDD: 80 GB

My question is which version of Hackintosh  i can install on my pc.